# New javascript array from json array getting only the values from the first

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON Array:

```
const arr = [ 
    { data: '250', name: 'john' },
    { data: '251', name: 'john' }
]:
```

How can i get from it, to a single new array having `[250, 251]` ?

I am not able to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [ { data: '250', name: 'john' }, { data: '251', name: 'john' } ];
let result = arr.map((x) => x.data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = [
  { data: "250", name: "john" },
  { data: "251", name: "john" },
];
let result = arr.map((x) => x.data);
console.log(result);

let list = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  list.push(arr[i].data);
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).